# Can something returned in one function be called by another class in Python?

Tags: python, class, return

I have the following code:

```
import ch
import re
import sys

def doMath(desIn):
  desOut = desIn+2
  return desOut

class bot(ch.RoomManager):
  def onMessage(self, room, user, message):
    try:
      cmd, args = message.body.split(" ", 1)
    except:
      cmd, args = message.body, ""

    if cmd=="!math":
      doMath(3)
      print(desOut)
```

I am using ch.py to run a bot in a Chatango chat room. It is designed to perform a certain task when a user sends out a specific message. In this case when a user sends the message of `"!math"`, I would like for it to call the doMath function with an input (`desIn`), perform the math operation I coded, and then return an output (`desOut`). In this case, it should return 5. My code runs all the way through, but it does not seem to print the last line that I wrote. Is it possible to return the output into the `bot` class I have?

By request, why does this not work?

```
def doMath(desIn):
  desOut = desIn+2
  return desOut

class A:
  doMath(3)
  print(desOut)
```

Comment: Is that story really relevant to the question in the title? Could you come up with a minimal example that does not rely on these specific modules in order to isolate the nature of the actual problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `desOut` variable is a local variable to the `doMath` function, which means it won't be accessible to the `onMessage` method. If you want your code to actually print the output of your `doMath` function, you have to either:

- Save it in a variable. That's useful if you want to use the same value somewhere else in the `onMessage` function:

```python
if cmd == '!math':
    math_output = doMath(3)
    print(math_output)
```

- Just print the returned value directly:

```py
if cmd == '!math':
    print(doMath(3))
```

You can read more details in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) or even more details [here](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html#variable-scope-and-lifetime).

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `print(doMath(int(3)))`. I just added `int` xD. If you want it to be a game, then:

```
if cmd == "!math":
    if args: room.message(doMath(int(args)))
    else: room.message(doMath(int(3)))
```

it would be like this:

```
>>> !math 5
>>> 7
>>> !math
>>> 5
```